# Grails app using mongo not starting on heroku

Tags: mongodb, grails, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Grails app on heroku but the deployments keep failing whilst wiring up my mongo beans.

The deployment method I am using is `heroku deploy:war`.

I have the `MONGOLAB_URI` set which I can check with the command, heroku config.
Reading their addon documentation, I take it that no mongo configuration is required within the application.

Stacktrace extract is as follows:

```
Error initializing the application: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [heroku_blahblah], username = [heroku_blahblah], password = [blahblah]
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: The plugin is throwing an authentication error. Have you checked your credentials?

Comment: @dmahapatro Basically I have used the credentials in the MONGOLAB_URI setting.However, when I try to connect to mongo on the command line, I get a login failed message: Error: { errmsg: "auth fails", ok: 0.0 }
Thu May 16 21:10:34 uncaught exception: login failed
exception: login failed